# Angular js, call module controller's method in the directive, which doesn't see it's scope by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is the issue: I have specified routes in the application config like:

```
when('/url', {
    controller: 'Controller',
    templateUrl: 'url'
  });
```

in the view I have only:

```
<div ng-view my-directive="fire()"></div>
```

the important thing that there are no 'ng-controller="MyController"' attribute.
when user loads url, the controller fires and template is filled with model data and rendered well.

then I have a directive that must do the following on the same page: when I click, the 'Controller' has to execute the function, get data and add render the template/add data to existing.

the directive is:

```
myAppModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'url',
    replace: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var raw = element[0];

        element.bind('click', function() {

                console.log('loaddata');
                scope.$apply(attrs.fire);

        });
      }

  };
});
```

the console.log is firing, but the `scope.$apply(attrs.fire)` - the fire() function inside the "Controller" doesn't. Key tips are:
if I add ng-controller="Controller" in the html it will work, but will fire twice when page will load. 
So how to tell directive to execute "Controller" fire method without using ng-controller="Controller"?

Comment: Can you show template that gets loaded? Also we not use ng-click instead of binding with jquery?

Comment: Hello Neil, sure, the template is: `<p>pagenum {{page}}</p>
<div ng-repeat='event in events'>
    <span>{{event.created}}</span>
    <span>{{event.order}}</span>
    <span>{{event.customer}}</span>
    <br />
    <span>{{event.user_name}}</span>
   </div>`. Generally it is a matter of binding events, click or other events, so we can abstract from click)

Comment: I think you need to try and recreate with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope.$eval()` for this, which will call the method.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var raw = element[0];
    var func = attrs.myDirective;   // gets the value fire()

    element.bind('click', function() {
            console.log('loaddata');
            scope.$eval(func);

            // you shouldn't need to call $apply here
            // since func will be executed within the 
            // controller
    });
}
```

Comment: not working with eval, temporary solution: removed controller name from route config and added controller parameter(controller name) to directive.